# Consultation freeloaders

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that sometimes certain users start asking relatively simple questions that look awfully like they're trying to get some free consultation out of people sharing their knowledge for good of our community. Their questions almost always contain links to their sites and it's very hard to answer those without doing their work wholesale for them. Those questions almost never benefit community as a whole either.

Those questions make me feel like somebody tries to use me. Today I saw several such questions and I wonder if I should vote them down or flag them or perhaps just ignore them?

UPDATE: An example can be found here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/9474/connor

Comment: Can you give examples?

Comment: Yes, examples to a few would be helpful.

Comment: I actually saw three of such questions (same user, same site) few days ago, but I'm unable to find those questions again. I'll update the question once I have good example. Or maybe somebody noticed them as well and can lend me a helping hand?

Comment: This is a question that toes the line in being a lot of work to come up with a meaningful answer: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22457/sku-auto-generator-with-prefix-and-sufix

Comment: (ran out of edit time) - A reply with substance should probably explain how to use event/observers, module creation, how EAV in magento works, implementing and overloading the backend model for the sku attribute and explaining that category isn't required so they'll need to make it so or be able to handle that use case. What happens when the category is changed outside of the edit product screen?

Comment: Another example: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24108/remove-arrow-buttons-for-product-viewpage-in-magento

Comment: Basically SE is for free consulting, open-source style. If you don't want to give, don't give. Some of us enjoy spending time coming up with answers to test our ability. If it's way too pandering just downvote it

Answer (score 2):

Looks for my like a reason to down vote.